# Why does getTimestamp on a DateTime field return a different result than selecting unix_timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime, jdbc

My table includes a datetime field:

```
`RunEndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
```

It's inserted as a UTC timestamp:

```
statement.setTimestamp(RUN_END_TIME, runStartTime, UTC_CALENDAR);
```

Where we have

```
Calendar UTC_CALENDAR = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

When I use a SQL query to the effect of

```
SELECT RunEndTime, unix_timestamp(RunEndTime) ...
```

I get different results for the following:

```
rs.getTimestamp(1);               // 1445423199000
rs.getTimestamp(1, UTC_CALENDAR); // 1445423199000
rs.getLong(2);                    // 1445408799
```

Selecting the `unix_timestamp` gives a different result, and it's the only accurate one. The other two are EDT, which is the location of the client program. How do I correctly use `getTimestamp`?

Comment: Is a [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html) set for MySQL?

Comment: @Tunaki set to SYSTEM, looks like UTC based on SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP());

Comment: Have a look at [JDBC/MySQL: Save timestamp always using UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206194/jdbc-mysql-save-timestamp-always-using-utc) -- it may be that you're affected by the [TimeZone discarded storing java.util.Calendar into DATETIME](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15604) bug and have to enable the bug fix by passing in `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` in the connector URL.

Comment: @Drew how's that relevant?

Comment: it overflows the bit registers

Comment: @Drew what does? how? why?

Comment: `rs.getLong(2);`  is a 32 bit overflow

Comment: @Drew I'm not saving it as an `int`, I'm printing it i.e. converting it to a String, and it's also the only # coming out to what I expect.

Comment: well then scratch that idea. I will look when I get a chance

Comment: Are you passing in `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` when you connect?

Comment: @MickMnemonic ah, on the query side. Yeah that looks to fix this problem, now I have just 2 more timezone bugs to track down and the system should be usable.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to understand -

- Firstly, `DateTime` objects are strings that do not contain timezones. They are not timestamps. When you call `unix_timestamp`, the function `unix_timestamp` implicitly takes a timezone and then calculates the seconds since the epoch using the `DateTime` and the timezone. The timezone for the server is probably set to UTC, but if you use `SET SESSION time_zone = '+04:00'` for instance, then call `unix_timestamp`, you will get a different answer. In other words, `unix_timestamp` does not output the the canonical timestamp associated with the DateTime because there is no canonical timestamp associated with the DateTime. The DateTime is just a timezone-unaware string. This is tangential to the problem but it something I failed to understand until researching it today, so including.
- That being said, the problem actually happens deep within the `rs.getTimestamp` call. It is a bug within MySQL (or JDBC or something). The fix for this is to add `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` when connecting to the database.